# How can I have faster sync with API?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-syncadapter, android-authenticator

I implemented AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter in Android for sync data with the server. But Android prevent less than 15 min period for the automatic sync in `API > 24`.

How can I implement shorter sync period (ex: 1min)?

Telegram has such a thing. It shows notification as soon as another user sends the message.

Comment: You can use push notification from service to client to have information in real time : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: SImple-  they aren't syncing.  They're pushing data from the server, then (possibly) requesting additional data in response to that push.

Comment: @Johann67 Does Telegram use Firebase for this?

Comment: I think Telegram use their own push system. But Firebase is a good notification system.